# Utilizar punto en url amigables

Tags: .htaccess

Deseo que el usuario al ingresar a **index.php** el contenido de la página cambie o varíe según el usuario que la ingreso.

LA url es algo como esto:

> www.dominio.com/login/nombre@elquesea.com

En mi .htaccess tengo la siguiente regla

```
RewriteRule ^tc/([@.a-z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?email=$1
```

Esa expresión me da error en el servidor por el punto, con el @ no tengo problema.

Alguna solución.

Gracias.

Comment: relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246044/how-to-add-dot-in-htaccess-rewrite-rule-regex

Comment: Lo cambie así pero igual no funciona

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user.php
RewriteRule ^tc/([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@/\.]+)$ user.php?work_email=$1